# Update field from None value to timestamp when click on Button

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a simple problem:
I have model Notification with fields:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', models.CASCADE, related_name='notifications')
    message = models.TextField('Message')
    viewed_at = models.DateTimeField('Seen at', null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Created', auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
```

And my logic is that Field viewed_at in DB is empty .
But when I click  on button "See it" This field will update with value timestamp now.
I created function in my views:

```
import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect



class NotificationListView(core.ListView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    model = Notification
    template_name = 'auth/notifications.html'


    def get_queryset(self):
        return Notification.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NotificationListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['unviewed_list'] = Notification.objects.filter(viewed_at__isnull=True,user=self.request.user)
        context['viewed_list'] = Notification.objects.filter(viewed_at__isnull=False, user=self.request.user)
        return context


def mark_as_read(request, notification_id):
    notification = Notification.objects.get(pk=notification_id)
    notification.viewed_at = datetime.datetime.now()
    notification.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST['next'])
```

My urls.py:

```
path('notification/<notification_id>/', views.mark_as_read, name='viewed-notification'),
```

And template ListView

```
<table class="table table-theme-3 text-left">
      <tbody>
        {% for item in unviewed_list %}
            <td>
              {{ item.message }}
            <td>
            <td>
              {{ item.created_at}}
              <td>
                  <span class="badge badge-error">
              <a class="button button--success button--sm" href="{% url 'users:viewed-notification' %}?next={{ request.path }}">
                      See it
                    </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
    </table>
```

I need that when I click on See it - model Field "viewed_at" update from None value on timestamp now!)Please what I am doing wrong in my code and why it does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the id to the view:

```
href="{% url 'users:viewed-notification' item.id %}?next={{ request.path }}">
```